# log space implementation in scheme

Tags: scheme

Implement logarithm function in scheme.

the logB function is enough to calculate logarithm

```
(define logB 
  (lambda (x b)
        (/ (log x) (log b)) 
    )
  )
```

then, I also need these 2 functions. why do I need these 2 functions?

this

```
(define logSpace
 (lambda (a b n x)
   (expt 10 (+ a (/ (* x (- b a)) (- n 1))))
       )
 )
```

and this one

```
 (define LogFunc
  (lambda (min max n x)         
    (logSpace
     (cond ((= min 0)    (logB 0.01 10))            
           ((< min 0)    (logB (* min -1) 10))
           (else         (logB min 10))) 

     (cond ((= max 0)    (logB 0.01 10))
           ((< max 0)    (logB (* max -1) 10))
           (else         (logB max 10))) 
     n 
     x)
)
```

)

Comment: What are those two functions supposed to do? The names don't make it clear.

Comment: If you only need logarithm procedure with base as argument the first procedure is sufficient.

Comment: what about this link : http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/flonum.html?q=log#%28tech._log._space%29

Comment: they explain about log space which I don't get...

Comment: We don't do 'hanging parens' in Lisp-based languages.  A 'hanging paren' is a paren on a line by itself.  Bunch them all up on the last line with any other text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need them.

Or perhaps you're misunderstanding the question that you've been given?

Comment: I spent another 5 minutes reading the code you submitted, and ... it's clear to me that you're not providing the needed context. You need to explain where this code comes from, and what it is you're asking. This is very vague.